# How to learn from time series with multiple values for each time points

Tags: keras, time-series, lstm, logistic-regression

A multivariate time-serie has more than one time-dependent variable and it is my case.

Still for each time I have not one entrie of dependent variables but many entries, like:

```
+======================================================================================================================================================================================+
| index, target, feature1, feature2, feature3, feature4, feature5, feature6, feature7, feature8, feature9, feature10, feature11, feature12, feature13, feature14, feature15, feature16 |
+======================================================================================================================================================================================+
| 2013-01-01, 1, 12, 0.006750, 21.192372, 39.119279, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13.602740, 117691.0, 0.06, 17259.0, 61491.0, 10.960000, 44620.0,                                                      |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2013-01-01, 1, 12, 0.256899, 21.192372, 39.119279, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30.282192, 835.0, 0.06, 221.0, 344.0, 10.004412, 406.0,                                                               |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2013-01-01, 0, 12, 0.000500, 21.192372, 39.119279, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30.282192, 49292.0, 0.04, 10853.0, 22945.0, 10.004412, 20132.0,                                                       |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I was trying to follow [this approach](https://www.kaggle.com/amirrezaeian/time-series-data-analysis-using-lstm-tutorial) applying LSTM, to give it a try, I res-sampled data by month, taking the average for each group. But this is far from reality and is a biased data especially when predicting target (binary).

Another thing to mention, my motivation of trying to learn from time, is that I have the impression it affects a lot other features, and thus, I can assume it have an unignorable influence on target.

Applying `train_dated[['feature1']].resample('M').mean()` on each of columns; shows trends and seasonality.

This is an example applying decomposition on one feature:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had such a problem earlier and that what I did is to 
separate the date to year, month and day.
I used logistic regression. 
For my side, it was helpful and the test percentage was 77%.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a multi-index (aka hierarchical) dataframe. This way you can properly arrange certain features into indices according to their timestamp. As it happens, I wrote a small piece on that, which you can use as an example (see the [linked github for code](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/exploring-recent-history-of-combustion-power-plants-in-the-netherlands-with-multi-index-dataframes-a45a74eb3217))